# Curl error: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure111

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I have error: Curl error: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure111
with this curl settings:

```
    $oCURL = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($oCURL, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt ($oCURL, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 4);
    curl_setopt($oCURL, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1');
    curl_setopt($oCURL, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, implode('&', $headers));
    curl_setopt($oCURL, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://' . PRZELEWY24_TYPE . '.przelewy24.pl/trnRegister');
    curl_setopt($oCURL, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($oCURL, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)');
    curl_setopt($oCURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($oCURL, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Comment: Don't turn off security, setup transport encryption properly instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> curl_setopt ($oCURL, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 4);
> ```

This enforces TLS 1.0. No idea why you restrict curl to a TLS protocol version which is kind of obsolete.

> ```
> curl_setopt($oCURL, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://' . PRZELEWY24_TYPE . '.przelewy24.pl/trnRegister');
> ```

It is unclear what `PRZELEWY24_TYPE` is. But assuming this is `sandbox` then the requests fails because the site in question does not support TLS 1.0 anymore, only more modern protocols like TLS 1.2 and TLS 1.3.

It is recommended that you simply neither set `CURLOPT_SSLVERSION` nor `CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST` but use the defaults instead - in which case it will likely work. Note also that you should also not set `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to false for a production site since this will open your client to easy man in the middle attacks.